# Makefile not printing ansi escape codes from other programs properly

Tags: makefile, colors, ansi-escape

Suppose i have a python file called `foo.py`.

```py
print('\x1b[34mfoo\x1b[0m')
```

And i have a makefile.

```
all:
  @python3 foo.py
```

When i run it normally through the terminal (by running `python3 foo.py`), it prints foo in blue.
However for some reason, when i run it by running `make` it just prints `←[34mfoo←[0m`.
This is not only for python too.

Comment: Having the same problem when running linting tools with a make command. `make lint` shows raw ANSI color codes, while running the commands directly works fine.
My guess is those tools don't setup the console using the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag.